Unit test - handleMethodCall - how to specify the return type?
I've created a mock object which implement public Object handleMethodCall().
One stubbedMethodName returns an object and the other returns a string.
How can I specify the expected return type?
Because actually I'm getting this error

System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to String


Ok, I've solved by the problem by adding
if (returnType.getName() == 'String') {
        return 'test';
      } else {
        return null;
      }

But in the same time I still don't understand how it works
